# Using C++ and libcurl to retrieve files from the Meijer account page

Tags: javascript, c++, curl, cookies, libcurl

I would like to use C++ and libcurl to retrieve files from my Meijer account page.  I would like to be here

https://www.meijer.com/mperks/ShoppingTools#receipts.

The login form lives here

https://accounts.meijer.com/manage/Account#/form/user

but exists on multiple pages.  In addition, any curl request I make to the above link, such as the following

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0" -L -e ";auto" -c cookie.txt https://accounts.meijer.com/manage/Account#/form/user
```

returns a page with a warning about the browser not supporting javascript.

Is what I want feasible given C++ and curl?

Comment: It looks like the pages you're trying to scrape are made with Angular (i.e. a single page app) which means the page is rendered client-side via JavaScript. `curl` won't execute the JavaScript required to render the page, so you get that message. You'll probably need to use something like a headless browser or WebDriver.

Comment: record logging in and getting the data you want with Fiddler Proxy, then write code the replicate the requests your browser made, with curl/c++

Comment: Thanks for the info.  It looks like something casperjs+phantomjs might be the avenue to pursue in this case.